# How to update the new page source everytime in scrapy xpath while using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

This selenium merged with scrapy is working fine with only one problem-

I need to update the `sites = response.xpath()` every time with the new source code the page generates otherwise it is returning me repetitive results again and again.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin
from selenium import webdriver
import time


class Product(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()


class FooSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'foo'

    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.download_delay = 0.25
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\chrm\chromedriver.exe")
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(60) # 

    def parse(self,response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)
        sites = response.xpath('//div[@class="single-review"]/div[@class="review-header"]')

        for i in range(0,200):
            items = []
            time.sleep(20)
            button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]/div[2]/div/div")
            button.click()
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(30)

            for site in sites:
                item = Product()

                item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="review-info"]/span[@class="author-name"]/a/text()').extract()
                yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new [`Selector` instance](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors) in the loop after the click passing the current page source from [`.page_source`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source):

```
from scrapy.selector import Selector

self.browser.implicitly_wait(30)

for i in range(0,200):
    time.sleep(20)  # TODO: a delay like this doesn't look good

    button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button[1]/div[2]/div/div")
    button.click()

    sel = Selector(text=self.browser.page_source)
    sites = sel.xpath('//div[@class="single-review"]/div[@class="review-header"]')

    for site in sites:
        item = Product()

        item['title'] = site.xpath('.//div[@class="review-info"]/span[@class="author-name"]/a/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Note that you need to call `implicitly_wait()` only once - it doesn't add an immediate delay - it only instructs `selenium` to wait X seconds when searching for elements.

Also, I doubt you really need `time.sleep(20)` call. Instead, you may want to start using [`Explicit Waits`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits).

Comment: @alexce the actual problem is that the content is genrated dynamically everytime when the button gets clicked is my question correct in that context?

Comment: getting error :       for site in sites:
  exceptions.TypeError: 'Selector' object is not iterable